# HaProxy Listen for both MySQL and HTTP

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I realise that using HAPROXY for databases and servers works better if the database servers are external and separate but is it possible to have 2 servers replicating database and files to each other and load balanced by 1 haproxy server ? having some trouble getting my haproxy file to work while listening for both, heres what I have so far:

```
     global
         log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
         maxconn 2000
         user haproxy
         group haproxy

     defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option redispatch
        timeout connect  5000
        timeout client  10000
        timeout server  10000

    listen servers 0.0.0.0:80
        mode http
        stats enable
        balance roundrobin
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        server server-1 1.1.1.1:80 check
        server server-2 2.2.2.2:80 check


    listen mysql-cluster
        bind 127.0.0.1:3306
        mode tcp
        option mysql-check user haproxy_check
        balance roundrobin
        server mysql-1 1.1.1.1:3306 check
        server mysql-2 2.2.2.2:3306 check
```

Comment: *"having some trouble"*  You'll need to be *much* more specific.  There is no reason this configuration shouldn't work fine.  That doesn't mean it's a good idea, necessarily, since in circular replication, only one database server should be written to... but that has nothing to do with HAProxy and everything to do with the way asynchronous circular replication works.  Your config says `mysql-cluster` which is a specific, non-standard version of MySQL Server, so you should also indicate whether you are really using the MySQL NDB/Cluster server or if you are using this word in a generic sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use HAProxy to balance MySQL TCP connections, but it's not as straightforward as with the HTTP connections.

- You need a better status checker. Something like a script under
  xinetd that will check that database is working and return http code
  200 or 503 if not. Without it HAProxy will be able only to detect if
  the port is open or not.
- Roundrobin balance spreads connection between
  both of you servers. It would be better to use the source hash to keep
  the sessions on the same server.
- You will need the master-master replication, but it's a disaster looking for a place to happen. Perhaps, it would be better to use the master-slave replication and the active-backup haproxy backends.
- Master-master will be working well with Galera replication. Maybe it's a way to go.
- You may also want to use Pacemaker or Keepalived insted of HAProxy to make a HA enables master-slave MySQL setup.
- You may also look at the MySQL proxy

Anyway, it's not easy and will require a lot of work to make it right. MySQL can be very quirky.

Comment: Great info man, will look into all of it. glad to hear its possible at least.